# SSO without SAML or OpenID Connect

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

What are the other options can we use for SSO with Salesforce as the identity provider if the other party does not support SAML or OpenID Connect?

Is it necessary to use a Custom Bridge that can transform the SAML message or an API driven solution?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to transform the incoming SAML or OIDC token to whatever the target supports. Alternatively, you can write a custom client in SF that speaks your own protocol but that's not recommended, token transformation is the right idea.

Comment: Thanks for the editing! Instead of SAML Is It possible tò make it with OAuth? Because the other systems accepts only OAuth. And the SSO needs tò happen from the Experience Cloud site

Comment: There are lots of ways to hack the experience but in terms of SSO protocols, there are only 2: OIDC and SAML.

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful as Always